# Demonstrating image compression, image isn't changing after first time

Tags: php

So, pretty simple little page I'm trying to write to demonstrate transcoding and compression. I can't figure out why the image doesn't seem to change after it does the first one.

```
<!-- imagemanipulation.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Image Transcoding Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Image Transcoding Example</h1>
<form action="imagemanipulation.php" method="POST">
Quality (0 - 100): <input type="text" name="quality" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['quality']) ? $_POST['quality'] : ""); ?>"><br />
Iterations: <input type="text" name="iterations" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['iterations']) ? $_POST['iterations'] : "")?>"><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<hr />

<?php
if (isset($_POST['quality']) && isset($_POST['iterations']))
{
    $quality = intval($_POST['quality']);
    $iterations = intval($_POST['iterations']);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpeg");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++)
    {
        ob_start();

        imagejpeg($image, NULL, $quality);

        $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

        echo "<img width=100 height=100 src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($rawImageBytes) . "' />";

        imagedestroy($image);
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($rawImageBytes);
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an intended behavior of the JPEG encoder. If an image encoded with a particular encoder configuration is decoded and reëncoded with that same configuration, the result will be the same as the original encoded image -- the "round-trip" does not alter the image.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your loop, you do :

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($rawImageBytes);
```

Each time, you're creating a new image of less quality and try to increment the quality. Or, you cannot improve the quality of this image!

You should remove this line and keep $image from the first image.jpeg.